# Is it accessible for a screen reader to have a button that acts as navigation and opens a accordion component?

Tags: accessibility

So the idea is that a intractable element might have the functionality of both a link and a button. The link would navigate to a new page while also opening a collapse element. I think that something like this would be inaccessible because a screen reader would not be able to read both actions. Is this the case or is there a workaround that allows the user to understand that both actions are taking place on press.

I don't have any code for this as this is more theoretical.

Comment: This seems problematic for all users. How would this work for people not using a screen reader? For all users, something is either a link or a button—not both. There are some well established accessible patterns for creating a navigation that has top-level items that are both links and have children; for example: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/examples/disclosure-navigation-hybrid/

Comment: This is what I thought as well thanks for the info!